# Telegram inputmedia to send video and photos

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am using python to send photos and images to telegram and when i send 1 image or video everything works fine. i have tried to send 2 and more videos/images. but telegram returns `bad request: can't parse media JSON object`. Parsed data:

```
{
    'chat_id': 123456781, 
    'caption': 'test', 
    'media': [
           {
                'type': 'video', 
                'media': 'attach://video0'
           }, 
           {
                'type': 'video', 
                'media': 'attach://video0'
            }
    ]
}
```

what is wrong with json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what was the problem, problem was with attached files. added file url instead `'media': 'attach://video0'` like `'media': 'fileurl'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on `editMessageMedia` method. It turned out that this method accepts media not as object, but as serialised string.

Comment: Hi @RomanRastiehaiev this is exactly my problem, could you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71242089/using-a-local-file-to-edit-image-of-a-message-in-the-telegram-channel