# Using a local file to edit image of a message in the Telegram channel

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Method I'm using is based on the model I use to create a new image publication in the channel, with the modifications it currently looks like:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36"
    }

image_file = 'jogos_de_hoje_na_tv_plus_watermark.png'
chat_telegram_channel = ['-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX']
idmessage = 16967

textalert = f'AAAAAAAAAA'
botalert = 'BBBBBBBBBBBB'
urlalert = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{botalert}/editMessageMedia'
photourl  = open(image_file, "rb")
params = {'caption':textalert, 'chat_id':chat_telegram_channel, 'message_id':idmessage, 'media':photourl, 'parse_mode':'HTML'}
requests.get(urlalert, headers=headers, params=params)
```

The request response is:

```
<html>
<head><title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>414 Request-URI Too Large</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Trying to use `POST` instead of `GET`:

```
data = {'caption':textalert, 'chat_id':chat_telegram_channel, 'message_id':idmessage, 'media':photourl, 'parse_mode':'HTML'}
requests.post(urlalert, headers=headers, data=data)
```

The response is:

```
{
    "ok":false,
    "error_code":400,
    "description":"Bad Request: can't parse input media JSON object"
}
```

According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68689553/11462274), it is necessary to serialize the string, well, I tried to do this:

```
photourl  = open(image_file, "rb")
data = {'caption':textalert, 'chat_id':chat_telegram_channel, 'message_id':idmessage, 'media':json.dumps(str(photourl)), 'parse_mode':'HTML'}
requests.post(urlalert, headers=headers, data=data)
```

But the response was:

```
{
    "ok":false,
    "error_code":400,
    "description":"Bad Request: can't parse InputMedia: expected an Object"
}
```

The API part for this need is:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagemedia

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should check the response of the request to check for error messages.

Comment: GET requests have a url limit, you are exceeding that limit by passing a large file to url. Instead you should use a POST request. You can read more about it here.

Comment: Hi @AliPadida When trying to use ```POST``` a new error is given as a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upload files using POST request.

This is how it's done, sending and editing a photo using post requests:

```py
import requests
import json

botToken = 'REPLACE_TOKEN'
chatId = 0 # REPLACE CHAT ID


def send_photo():
    image = "image.jpg"
    address = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{botToken}/sendPhoto'
    data = {"chat_id": chatId, "caption": "before edit"}
    with open(image, "rb") as imageFile:
        result = requests.post(address, files={"photo": imageFile}, data=data).json()
        if result["ok"]:
            return result["result"]["message_id"]
        else:
            raise Exception(result["description"])
    return


def edit_photo(message_id):
    image = "image2.jpg"
    address = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{botToken}/editMessageMedia'
    media = {"type": "photo", "media": "attach://photo", "caption": "after edit"}
    data = {"chat_id": chatId, "message_id": message_id, "media": json.dumps(media)}
    with open(image, "rb") as imageFile:
        requests.post(address, files={"photo": imageFile}, data=data)
    return


edit_photo(send_photo())
```

Comment: Hi @AliPadida Just a small question, always at the end of a ```def``` function, should put a ```return``` even if like in this case it doesn't return any value? is this a good practice too?

Comment: My question is because in the ```def send_photo()``` the ```return``` is returning ```Code is unreachable``` in visual studio code, as if it were disabled.

Comment: @BrondbyIF It's ok to remove the ending return, that's my habit to always place an ending return on every function.

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts, I figured out how to proceed for serialize the string and then edit:

```
import requests
import json

BOT_TOKEN = 'AAAAAAAAAA'
chat_telegram_channel = 'BBBBBBBBBB'
idmessage = 16967

image_file = 'jogos_de_hoje_na_tv_plus_watermark.png'
urlalert = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/editMessageMedia'
textalert = f'Programação de jogos na TV\nPowered by:\n@mattosxperiences'

files = {
    'media': open(image_file, "rb")
}
media = json.dumps({
    'caption':textalert,
    'type': 'photo',
    'media': 'attach://media'
})
params = { 
    'chat_id':chat_telegram_channel, 
    'message_id':idmessage, 
    'media': media,
    'parse_mode':'HTML'
    }

requests.get(urlalert, params=params, files=files)
```

Comment: Do not upload files with GET request, that's a bad practice. Uploading files is always done by a POST request.

Comment: Hi @AliPadida , could you create an answer with the model specifically for ```POST```, please? That way I can fix your answer as a solution for the case and with the addition of being perfectly in accordance with good usage practices!

Comment: I added my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71254170/4484994).

Answer (score 0):

remove `photourl` from data and put it in request `files` parameter as below :

```
photourl = open(image_file, "rb")
data = {
'caption':textalert, 'chat_id':chat_telegram_channel, 'message_id':idmessage,
'parse_mode':'HTML'
}
files = {'media':photourl}
requests.post(urlalert, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)
```